# Will unsetting Laravel sessions make all other user logged out also?

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4

I'm doing Laravel 4 web where I store all user's information when they logged in using `Session::put('key','value')`. When user logs out there are two methods i know to unset it, `Session::forget('key')` and `Session::flush()`.

My question is, when i do Session::forget() or flush(), will other user that's still logged in will be logged out also? Is there any way to test this?

Answer (score 1):

No, forgetting session will logout the user who logged-in with that specific system and the other remote users will not be logged-out.

I have already tested this with one of my project.

You can use the `Auth::logout();` function for user logout operation, which will forge the session internally.

Using the Session::forget() and Session::flush() will clear the current user from that browser.

Check API here http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Auth.Guard.html#382-399

Comment: thanks, i cannot use `Auth` though since the way i authenticate users are not using the usual `Auth::attempt`

Comment: Ok, then you can unset the session manually by ``Session::flush()`` or ``forget()``